# IPython Notebook & %rmagic - Can't find shared libraries

Tags: r, gdal, jupyter-notebook, rgdal, osgeo

I have been using IPython Notebook to integrate my Python and R code into one workflow in the generating some spatial analyses.  I had previously been able to import the necessary infrastructure into both namespaces to perform this task, but I think something has changed due to a subsequent update.  In particular, I am no longer able to call the **rgdal** library in an *%%R* cell:

```
%%R

library(rgdal)
***************
Loading required package: sp
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/choct155/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
  /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgdal’
```

The reason this is odd is because I can call the library in base R and RStudio (the outputs are identical):

```
> library(rgdal)
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 0.8-11, (SVN revision 479M)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.10.0, released 2013/04/24
Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal/1.10
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012, [PJ_VERSION: 480]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
```

The version information in RStudio and Notebook is the same...:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          0.1                         
year           2013                        
month          05                          
day            16                          
svn rev        62743                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
nickname       Good Sport
```

...as is the location of R:

```
> Sys.which("R")
           R 
"/usr/bin/R"
```

Note that I attempted to install **rgdal** from within Notebook...:

```
%%R

install.packages("rgdal")
************************
Installing package into ‘/home/choct155/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'http://watson.nci.nih.gov/cran_mirror/src/contrib/rgdal_0.8-11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 1607285 bytes (1.5 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.5 Mb


The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpDTrZOJ/downloaded_packages’
```

...and it is the same version as that which has been successfully loaded in RStudio:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgdal_0.8-11 sp_1.0-11   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.1      lattice_0.20-23 tools_3.0.1
```

And with that, I am at a loss for what's happening here.  While I can proceed in RStudio, it fragments the product I am attempting to create.  Any advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

**ADDENDUM:** It appears that this may not just be an issue with %rmagic.  In attempting to perform a different operation in Python, I received the following error when attempting to import both **osgeo** and **gdal**:

```
import gdal

************************

ERROR: ImportError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name [IPython.core.interactiveshell]
ERROR:astropy:ImportError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-27bf4694dd2b> in <module>()
----> 1 import gdal

/home/choct155/analysis/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdal.py in <module>()
      1 # import osgeo.gdal as a convenience
----> 2 from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
      3 deprecation_warn('gdal')
      4 
      5 from osgeo.gdal import *

/home/choct155/analysis/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in <module>()
     19                 fp.close()
     20             return _mod
---> 21     _gdal = swig_import_helper()
     22     del swig_import_helper
     23 else:

/home/choct155/analysis/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in swig_import_helper()
     15         if fp is not None:
     16             try:
---> 17                 _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
     18             finally:
     19                 fp.close()

ImportError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name
```

I literally just installed GDAL again, so I have the most up-to-date version.  Thoughts?